# How to generate custom URL in MVC3, instead of passing my parameters as query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, url-routing

When I type the URL like ../Search/Recipes/Deserts/Pie, I can get redirected to that page (i.e in SearchController, action method would be Recipes & parameters would be Deserts & Pie .

NB: To achieve the same I ve added a route in my Global.asax, that looks like :

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "SearchRecipes",                                              
            "Search/Recipes/{category}/{type}",                           
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Recipes", category = "all" , type = ""}  
 );
```

But how to generate that URL through our code? When I try to add a route value in Url.Action, it comes as a query string.

For example,

`Url.Action( "Recipes" , "Search" , new { type = item.type, isPie = item.isPie} )`

would give me link that looks like : `Search/Recipes?type=Deserts&isPie=Y`,

but I want to generate url like `Search/Recipes/Deserts/Y`.

Please let me know how we can achieve the same?

Basically I dont want to pass my parameters as query string, but want to adhere to \ separated values.

Comment: This new route looks exactly the same as the last route, except the parameters are different. How is the routing engine supposed to tell them apart?

Comment: Or do you mean why isn't this action getting matched to the existing route?

Comment: @32bitkid : Basically I dont want to pass my parameters as query string, but want to adhere to \ separated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "SearchRecipes",                                              
        "Search/Recipes/{category}/{type}/{isPie}",                           
        new { controller = "Search", action = "Recipes", category = "all" , type = "", isPie="N"}  
  );
@Url.RouteUrl("SearchRecipes",new{category=item.Category,type=item.type,isPie=itme.isPie})
```

Any query parameter not specified when defining a route will be added as ?param=value

Comment: I am getting "/" as the value in my url, i.e. string url = @Url.RouteUrl("SearchRecipes",new{category=item.Category,type=item.type,isPie=itme.isPie});

Comment: Can you post your route definitions?

Comment: My route defination is  routes.MapRoute("myRoute",
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{age}/{address}/{zip}/{opt}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "GetStuff",
                    age = 0,
                    address = "DummyAddress",
                    zip = 0,
                    name = "Dell",
                    opt = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
           );

Comment: and string url = @Url.RouteUrl("myRoute", new { name = Model.Nmae, age = Model.Age, address = Model.Address, zip = Model.zipCode, opt = Model.OptParameter });
} is yielding "/" as its value.

Comment: Afaik, the route is yelding '/' when the route values match the route defaults. Try debugging to see exactly what values goes to the helper

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UrlHelper.RouteUrl method

```
Url.RouteUrl("SearchRecipes", new {category = item.category, type=item.type});
```